# 'Error Splicing File: Input/Output Error' When Copying from a CD

Tags: cd

I'm trying to copy some files from a CD to my harddrive, but I keep getting the error:

`Error Splicing File: Input/Output Error`

The files ARE still copying, but only at about 2.5kB/s and the CD drive doesn't sound like it's doing much. I doubt it's a problem with filenames, since the disc appears to have been created on Windows, which to me seems to be stricter about what can & can't go in a filename. Nautilus shows the disc's format is UDF, although it also shows the disc's size is 0 bytes (with 0 in use) and contains about 3MB of stuff, even though the folder I'm trying to copy is bigger than that. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 2):

It is because the files that were written to the CD had not finished writing in the first place. The folder that was copied to the CD has broken files. The files when written onto the CD gets saved in distributed parts. When they don't get written completely, you get these errors.

There is no problem with the format. Try writing the whole content over again with a fresh CD.

Comment: It was a gift, and has a ton of stuff on it. Is there a way to fix it without a copy of the original files?

Comment: If a file hasn't been completely written to disk then that means there are parts that are simply missing. Unless there is some redundancy system in place (doubtful) those files cannot be fixed